# Angular Slider not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I implemented an angular slider on my site, and I have the issue that it is not showing up. There are no errors reported in the console.

[image]

I implemented it this way:

index.html

```
  <script src="/../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/../bower_components/angularjs-
      slider/dist/rzslider.min.js"></script>
   ...
  <body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-9">
     <p>Date Range:</p><br>
          <rzslider class="custom-slider"
          rz-slider-model="dateSlider.minValue"
          rz-slider-high="dateSlider.maxValue"
          rz-slider-options="dateSlider.options"></rzslider>
  ...
```

And the controller:

```
angular.module('myapp', []).controller('ctrl', 
function($scope, $http, $rootScope, gservice){
$scope.dateSlider = {
        minValue: '1',
        maxValue: '4',
        options: {
            stepsArray: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    };
  }
```

My app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ctrl', 'gservice', 'rzModule']);
```

What might the cause of this be?

Comment: Did you include the slider library JS file and injected it?

Comment: @Tushar Yes I did, updated above.

Comment: @ffritz: did you included `rzModule` module? , like `angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);` ?, see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3jjye1cL/)

Comment: @anoop It is included in my app.js as added above. Does it also have to be included in the dependencies of the controller itself? --Edit: Yes it does. Thanks! :)

Comment: Your controller is fine. You probably didn't include something right. Check this demo fiddle and see if you missed something
https://jsfiddle.net/ValentinH/954eve2L/

Comment: @masterfan Already solved, thanks, forgot the dependency in the controller.

Comment: @anoop I know, still waiting for my coffee :P Feel free to write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct our `module declaration` and the way to register `controller\service\factory.`

In above code, remove empty dependency `[]`, else it will create new module. Reuse the existing declared module like :

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('ctrl', 
function($scope, $http, $rootScope, gservice){
$scope.dateSlider = {
        minValue: '1',
        maxValue: '4',
        options: {
            stepsArray: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }
    };
  },
```

and remove `ctrl, gservice` from module dependency array., Like:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['rzModule']);
```

as, you can register Controller\service with existing module `myapp`

**further** `gservice`, seems to be some `service` and can also be registered to existing module., Like:

`angular.module('myapp').service('gservice', function(\\`

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have forgot to link rzslider.css and ui-bootstrap-tpls.js.
You may also need to define the ng-app in your HTML.

    `<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://rawgit.com/rzajac/angularjs-slider/master/dist/rzslider.css'>`

    `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>`

You may see the live code in jsfiddle that I tested your code.

https://jsfiddle.net/abhijd88/2eupcen8/6/